# Does Popen().stdout.close() return a value?

Tags: python, python-2.7, popen

I have in the code I maintain:

```
app7z = dirs['mopy'].join('7z.exe').s # path to 7z.exe
command = '"%s" a "%s" -y -r "%s\\*"' % (app7z, dstFile.temp.s, srcDir.s)
ins = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, startupinfo=startupinfo).stdout
#--Error checking and progress feedback
reCompressing = re.compile('Compressing\s+(.+)')
regMatch = reCompressing.match
reError = re.compile('Error: (.*)')
regErrMatch = reError.match
errorLine = []
for line in ins:
    maCompressing = regMatch(line)
    if len(errorLine) or regErrMatch(line):
        errorLine.append(line)
    if maCompressing:
        # update progress
result = ins.close() # THIS
if result:
    dstFile.temp.remove()
    raise StateError(_("%s: Compression failed:\n%s") % (dstFile.s, 
                       "\n".join(errorLine)))
```

([full code](https://github.com/wrye-bash/wrye-bash/blob/921bee0e34495e6c07a13a6bf32dcd555c0b1d58/Mopy/barb.py#L297-L324))

Does `ins.close()` return a non None value on failure ? My IDE (pycharm 3.4.2/4.5.2) warns me that it does not, but then not consistently.

I am on windows if this makes a difference - python 2.7.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you think, `close` can return?
You probably want to use `wait` to get the exit code:

```
app7z = dirs['mopy'].join('7z.exe').s # path to 7z.exe
command = [app7z, 'a', dstFile.temp.s, "-y", "-r", os.path.join(src.Dir.s, '*')]
process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, startupinfo=startupinfo)
out = process.stdout
regMatch = re.compile('Compressing\s+(.+)').match
regErrMatch = re.compile('Error: (.*)').match
errorLine = []
for line in out:
    maCompressing = regMatch(line)
    if len(errorLine) or regErrMatch(line):
        errorLine.append(line)
    if maCompressing:
        # update progress
result = process.wait()
if result:
    dstFile.temp.remove()
    raise StateError(_("%s: Compression failed:\n%s") % (dstFile.s, 
                       "\n".join(errorLine)))
```

Comment: I did not write the code and I do not expect anything - whoever wrote that probably expected close to return a 'non zero' value for failure. Now would I need to wait ? Apparently the code reads `7z` output line by line and would know if an error occurred. Or is it better style to just wait anyway ? Also - would I need to still `close()` if I call wait ?

Comment: Apparently wait can deadlock - would it be better to use communicate() - and then check err for non null value ? Also do I need to out.close() ? Thanks

Comment: Ask a different question for those: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30982217/python-popen-wait-vs-communicate-vs-calledprocesserror